# JavaFX, Maven and SceneBuilder - image doesn't load

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

The image shows in SceneBuilder, but as you can see at the picture below, in java application it doesn't load (even though the Intellij detects image's presence). My bet is that it has something to do with Maven, but I have no idea how to fix it...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was right about Maven, since it messes with the resource path.

All I had to do was change `<Image url="@../../../resources/logo.png" />`

to `<Image url="@/logo.png" />`

in .fxml file